# Problem with Javascript's 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have the following HTML markup :

```
<a class="link1" href="javascript:load(0,1);">Click here</a><span class="loader"></span>
```

The load function is defined as follows :

```
function load(flag,id){

    /*Load Forum*/
    if(flag==0){
        $(this).next("span.loader").html("<img src='./images/loader.gif'/>");
    console.log("Here");
    //....Some code follows
```

So what I want is the preloader gif should appear beside the link when it is clicked. The 'console.log' is printing 'Here' to the console but the image is not appearing. The image is located at the correct address. I think there is problem in the way I am using the 'this' keyword. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. :)

Updated: As it was pointed out by some, I passed reference to the  element by passing this as an argument. Here is my code now but it does not work still :

```
<a class="link1" href="javascript:load(0,1,this);">Click here</a><span class="loader"></span>


function load(flag,id,ref){
/*Load Forum*/
if(flag==0){
    if(ref){ $(ref).next("span.loader").html("123");console.log("Here"); }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you bind your event handler with jQuery instead of using the "href" (which is a really bad habit anyway), then your `this` value would be correct.

```
$(function() {
  $('a.link1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).data('flag') === '0') {
      $(this).next('span.loader').html('<img/>', { src: './images/loader.gif' });
      // ...
    }
  });
});
```

That also implies that the markup would change:

```
<a class='link1' href='#' data-flag='0'>Click here</a>
```

Binding the handler through jQuery means that the library will make sure that `this` refers to the element for which the handler is being invoked; that is, the `<a>` tag.  The way you have it (with the "href" pseudo-URL), that would not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is to use javascript:load.call(this, 0, 1) but Pointy is right.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong, meder is correct about the javascript pseudo protocol causing the issue. you could however do href='#' onclick='load.call(this, 0, 1)'

Answer (score 0):

The context is `window` because you're referencing it with the `javascript:` pseudo protocol. I would unobtrusively attach it.

```
<a id="link" href="#">jkfds</a>
<script>
   (function(){
        var l = document.getElementById('link');
        l.onclick = function() {
           load.call( this, 0, 1 );
           return false; // if needed
        };
        function load(one,two){ alert(one); alert(two); alert(this.nodeName); }
   })();
</script>
```

The context defaults to the anchor since we're not executing it in global context, since the anonymous function is attached to the DOMElement ( anchor node ) and the context is passed via `.call`.

If you need the parameters on the DOM element itself, just use `data-` attributes and reference them with `.getAttribute` ( assuming it works consistently in IE6 )

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a class="link1" href="#" flag="0">Click here</a><span class="loader"></span>
```

and

```
$("a.link1").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr("flag") ==0){
        $(this).next("span.loader").html("<img src='./images/loader.gif'/>");
        console.log("Here");
    }
})
```

Comment: It would probably be advisable to use a data attribute rather than making one up.  `flag=0` would become `data-flag=0` and the jQuery would be `$(this).data("flag") == 0`

Comment: Shane, Interesting.  Is there a performance difference between the two methods?

Comment: not aware of the performance difference, but the method I mention is the HTML5 standard for defining data (from what I understand, anyway...) which would lead me to expect native browser support at some point...

Answer (score 0):

untested

```
<a class="link1">Click here</a><span class="loader"></span>

    $('.link1').click(function() {
        load(flag, id);
    }

    function load(flag,id){

        /*Load Forum*/
        if(flag==0){
            $(this).next("span.loader").html("<img src='./images/loader.gif'/>");
        console.log("Here");
        //....Some code follows
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pointy is right that there are better ways to do this, but if you can't refactor, you can pass `this` as another parameter of your javascript call...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example that assumes you were using the `load(flag, id)` function multiple places: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GRcXS/.  The main issue was that the value of "this" is the browser window, not the element when you assign the event handler using javascript:.  Since you have jQuery, it's much better to use jQuery to hook up the click event and it will then set the `this` point appropriately.

HTML:

```
<a class="link1" data-flag="0" href="#">Click here</a>
<span class="loader"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
function load(flag,id){
    /*Load Forum*/
    if(flag == 0) {
        $(this).next("span.loader").html("<img src='http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344291068_HdnTo-Ti.jpg'/>");
        console.log("Here");
        //....Some code follows
    }
    return(false);
}

$(".link1").click(function() {
    return(load.call(this, $(this).data("flag"), 1));
});
```